# How to have a widget on your app that can open without the need for passcode?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm designing an app in Phonegap so I'm using HTML, CSS, Javascript etc.

This app uses the phones camera (a QR scanner to be exact) and I want the users to be able to use this app as quick as possible. So, like on my Android device I can access the camera without typing the password, is there a way you can do the same with your app ?

Application is still in the design stages so I'm getting everything together first to make sure what I want can be developed before I start the development, thank you.

Comment: you can developer native plugin in phonegap , or go to TitaniumStudio much better than phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can define the attribute `widgetCategory` in your `appwidget-provider` to `home_screen|keyguard`

```
    <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:minWidth="40dp"
         android:minHeight="40dp"
         android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
         android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
         android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
         android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure" 
         android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
         android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"> //like here
</appwidget-provider>
```

But as per [Google documents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), this feature has been taken down from `Android 5.0 Lollipop` (only `home_screen` will be valid) so it will work for devices supporting `Android 4.2 or above` but below `Android 5.0` which will be too limited.

> The widgetCategory attribute declares whether your App Widget can be
>   displayed on the home screen (home_screen), the lock screen
>   (keyguard), or both. Only Android versions lower than 5.0 support
>   lock-screen widgets. For Android 5.0 and higher, only home_screen is
>   valid.

Comment: very informative, so basically I wont be able to do it on new devices :(( thanks for the response

Comment: Yes I am not aware of how to program it using `Phonegap` etc but it is of no use as per new devices will not be able to support it.

Comment: You can use the Adenda SDK to make custom interactive lock screens on Android 5 and above 
http://www.adendamedia.com/